# Averageif cell(s) not blank

Tags: excel, if-statement, average, zero, nonblank

I am trying to average a percentage commission range on another sheet. On sheet Lines Sales column K I can enter a percentage commission charge if there is one. More frequently I don't have a commission as I am selling my own property.

Through my various searches on here I found that Excel should ignore blank cells in this function and if I want to ignore zeros I should format like this:

```
=AVERAGEIF('Line Sales'!K2:'Line Sales'!K150,"<>0")
```

In using this formula with no commissions entered I get a `#DIV/0!` error. As soon as I enter a commission percentage on a line I get a valid result. I plan to start a new workbook each year to track what I do but I don't want to spend possibly months looking at that error until I get a commission sale.

What I hope to accomplish is to average only commission percentages from `K2` to `K150` on the Line Sales sheet and have this formula entered into Totals sheet `B13`, if there are no commission sales I'd like to see it remain blank or be zero.

Comment: Also relevant there should be no zeros, only blank or a percentage in the cells.

Comment: =AVERAGE('Line Sales'!K2:'Line Sales'!K150) still gives the #DIV/0! error.

Comment: I don't know what is the problem. In my Excel 2010, if some cell is blank `average()` ignores it and if some cell is zero `average()` includes it. No `#DIV/0!` error. Please provide a sample Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

`#DIV/0!` error is the expected result for `AVERAGEIF` if there is nothing to average (it's basically doing the calculation 0/0), so just wrap in an `IFERROR` function to make the result blank or zero, e.g.

`=IFERROR(AVERAGEIF('Line Sales'!K2:K150,"<>0"),"")`

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I needed. Thanks!